# Behavior when Oozie job misses turn

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have a Oozie coordinator job setup to run at 12 AM UTC everyday. I am looking for a mechanism using which I can ask Oozie to re-run those jobs which were missed because Oozie server was down.

I understand that through SLA parameters in the `workflow.xml` file, I can specify SLA's of job duration and email contacts, but was not sure what happens in the following situation:

- The oozie job is scheduled to run on July 07, 00:05 UTC
- But, the oozie server goes down : July 06, 23:00 UTC
- Oozie server comes back up on: July 08, 00:30 UTC

In this case, will Oozie understand that it has missed to execute July 07, and current July 08, run? Any configurations that I have to take care of ?

Comment: not sure that I understand the question. if Oozie is down - when it come back  it need to restart with some start date- what is it ?

Comment: Were you able to successfully use Oozie's SLA feature. If yes, can you please help answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281650/oozie-not-sending-sla-email-alerts

Answer (score 0):

Oozie automatically runs all previous scheduled workflows in the coordinator. However it will not rerun previous failed jobs.

If your server is down on July 6 and comes back on July 8, then it will run july 7th first and then july 8th job.

I think you don't need to set any paramter for this. This is default behaviour of oozie.

Comment: FYI you can control the order of those job , meaning you can tell oozie to start with 8th job and than the 7th job